# Python: print tuple gives empty string

Tags: numpy, printing, format, tuples, expand

I try to make a formatted print of numpy matrix size in the format "NRows x NCols":

```
Test.shape
>>(1587L,)
```

that I want to see as **"1587 x 1"**.

However I cannot achieve this with formatted print:

```
print "{Dims[0]} x {Dims[1]}".format(Dims=Test.shape)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/Scripts/Python/Formatted Print", line 3, in <module>
    print "{Dims[0]} x {Dims[1]}".format(Dims=a)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can you suggest a code snippet to make a desire output without many ifs to check different cases please?

Thank you!

Comment: `Test` is a 1D array, hence `shape` reports only one dimension, if `Test` was a 2D array, created by for instance `np.zeros((1587,1))`, `shape` would be a tuple with two items.

Comment: OK. Got it. Is it possible to use "default" values, which are substituted to empty values in _print.format_?